# How to pass nested params in android RequestParams()

Tags: android, android-async-http

I am using android-async-http library to fetch json from url by passing params using `RequestParams()`, When parameters are not nested it is working without any problem, but my url contains nested params and I don't understand how to add those params to `RequestParams()`

URL to fetch data from:

```
https://www.someurl.com/something/v3/something/something?view=READER&fields=description,locale(country,language),name,pages/totalItems,posts/totalItems,published,updated,url&key=my_key
```

I want to know how to add `locale(country,language)` and `pages/totalItems`

My MainActivity

```
public void getBlogInformation() throws JSONException {

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("key", "123asdf456ghjklabcdefghijklmn");
    params.put("view", "reader");
    params.put("fields", "description");

    //How to add next params???
    params.put("locale", );

    BlaBlaRESTClient.get("", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
           try {
                Log.d("Response ", ""+response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

            Log.d("Error: ", ""+errorResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query string has the following field-value pairs (or parameters):

- **view**: *READER*
- **fields**: *description,locale(country,language),name,pages/totalItems,posts/totalItems,published,updated,url*
- **key**: *my_key*

There's no parameters such as 'locale', it is part of one of your values. So you CANNOT pass it as

```
params.put("locale", "[whateveryouputhere]");
```

as it would be outputed similar to:

```
...?view=reader&locale=[whateveryouputhere]&...
```

I assume now that the API you are calling is not under your control and the parameters have to be in that specific form. That means you have to URL encode the value as it contains chars conflicting with chars used in URLS:

```
description,locale(country,language),name,pages/totalItems,posts/totalItems,published,updated,url
```

as

```
description%2Clocale(country%2Clanguage)%2Cname%2Cpages%2FtotalItems%2Cposts%2FtotalItems%2Cpublished%2Cupdated%2Curl
```

So you would populate your RequestParameters like:

```
params.put("key", "123asdf456ghjklabcdefghijklmn");
params.put("view", "reader");
params.put("fields", "description%2Clocale(country%2Clanguage)%2Cname%2Cpages%2FtotalItems%2Cposts%2FtotalItems%2Cpublished%2Cupdated%2Curl");
```

Of course you would replace 'description' with a proper description, and 'totalItems' with an integer. But the principle remains the same. The server then will take the parameters **fields** and parses the string-value into its individual values.

See here for details:
[URL Query String Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

See here for URL encoding:
[URL Encoding/Decoding Tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)